# How to display the json data in multiautocomplete textview?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, fragment, android-cursoradapter

I am new to android, am developing one application in which i have to get the data from the server need to store that data in sqlite, so every time i should not hit the server,when ever i want get from database,in this app i used fragment concept,when i enter the single character in multiautocomplete textview based on the names in `json` response it needs to show the email-ids which are matching to that character in drop down list. i have done the code am not getting errors but not getting the expected result in `textview`

when i debug the code the following block of code is not executing i don't know what is the problem in this can you please help me any one

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Cursor cursor = contactDataSource.getAllData();

                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "total contcat count :" + cursor.getCount());

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)

                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Contact from cursor:"
                                        + cursor.getString(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(ExistingContactTable.COL_NAME)));

                }

                customAdapter = new CustomContactAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);

                Log.i("Custom contact adapter", "" + customAdapter);


                if (customAdapter != null)

                    editorIdSharableEmail.setAdapter(customAdapter);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your all data in array by json 
and then use that array

```
  String[] str={"Andoid","Jelly Bean","Froyo",
                "Ginger Bread","Eclipse Indigo","Eclipse Juno"};

    MultiAutoCompleteTextView mt=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

    mt.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);

    mt.setThreshold(1);
    mt.setAdapter(adp);
```

if you dont know how to get data from json then check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and also check [this](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/multiautocompletetextview.php)